# In bitrix24 CRM how to search lead using phone number

Tags: api, crm, bitrix

In bitrix24 CRM how to search lead,contacts or company details using phone number in PHP,there are no any proper documentation to refer.

If any body can help me,it's really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Following code uses new Bitrix D7 ORM API to retrieve lead by phone number.

```
<?php
\Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('crm');

$arLeads = \Bitrix\Crm\LeadTable::getList(array(
    "filter" => array("PHONE_MOBILE" => "+79876543210")
))->fetchAll();

print_r($arLeads);
?>
```

How to use filter is described in following API docs: https://www.bitrixsoft.com/help/index.html?page=source%2Fiblock%2Fhelp%2Fen%2Fdeveloper%2Fclasses%2Fciblockelement%2Fgetlist.php.html

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for you reply.

Comment: thanks for your reply,But can i know where to download library to use mentioned code.

Comment: D7 is the core of the Bitrix24 so you don't need to install it, just use it.

Comment: Hi,thanks.But i am using cloud bitrix crm,so how can i use "\Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('crm')" ,this line in my code,it gives me error.

Comment: You should mention it in your question. For cloud version in PHP you could use bitrix24-php-sdk - see  https://github.com/mesilov/bitrix24-php-sdk 
It wraps B24 REST API.